# one-line way to find the index of string with specific substring in list

Tags: python

Is there a *one-line* way to find the `index` of a string with a specific `substring` in a `list`?

I have a `list` like `['abc1', 'abc2', 'abc3', 'abc4']` and I wanna know what is the `index` where I have the `substring` `4`.

Comment: What if more than one of the items has that substring?  What if none of them do?

Comment: It's not that case.

Comment: @bmelo: Better to include this extra info in your question

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?

```
items = ['abc1', 'abc2', 'abc3', 'abc4']
substring = '4'
index = [i for i, item in enumerate(items) if substring in item][0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for that, i.e.:

```
i = [i for i, s in enumerate(items) if '4' in s]
```

---

[Python Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/QDj)

Answer (score 2):

Since, there is only one item containing `'4'` (like you say), go for a generator:

```
items = ['abc1', 'abc2', 'abc3', 'abc4']
substring = '4'

index = next((i for i, x in enumerate(items) if substring in x), None)
# 3
```

Additionally a `None` to handle case when there is no string with `'4'`.